# Problems with javascript loop adding GMarker to GMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, loops

I am having problems adding GMarkers when using a loop. The best way to explain the problem is to show the code, I guess :)

This works:

```
htmls[0] = "<div style=\"margin-bottom:10px; \"><table><tr><td><img src=\"" + result[0].UserImageURI + "\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\" /></td><td style=\"vertical-align:top; \"><strong>" + result[0].Username + "</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (" + result[1].Age + ")<br/>" + result[0].Country + "<br/>" + result[0].Distance + " KMs away<br/><a href=\"profile.aspx?lfid=" + result[0].Userid + "\">View Profile</a></td></tr></table></div>";
    latlngs[0] = new GLatLng(result[0].Latitude, result[0].Longitude);
    if (result[0].Gender == "F") {
        markers[0] = new GMarker(latlngs[0], { draggable: false, icon: fIcon });
    } else {
        markers[0] = new GMarker(latlngs[0], { draggable: false, icon: mIcon });
    }
    GEvent.addListener(markers[0], "click", function () {
        markers[0].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[0]);
    });
    map.addOverlay(markers[0]);
    htmls[1] = "<div style=\"margin-bottom:10px; \"><table><tr><td><img src=\"" + result[1].UserImageURI + "\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\" /></td><td style=\"vertical-align:top; \"><strong>" + result[1].Username + "</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (" + result[1].Age + ")<br/>" + result[1].Country + "<br/>" + result[1].Distance + " KMs away<br/><a href=\"profile.aspx?lfid=" + result[1].Userid + "\">View Profile</a></td></tr></table></div>";
    latlngs[1] = new GLatLng(result[1].Latitude, result[1].Longitude);
    if (result[1].Gender == "F") {
        markers[1] = new GMarker(latlngs[1], { draggable: false, icon: fIcon });
    } else {
        markers[1] = new GMarker(latlngs[1], { draggable: false, icon: mIcon });
    }
    GEvent.addListener(markers[1], "click", function () {
        markers[1].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[1]);
    });
    map.addOverlay(markers[1]);
```

But when I put it in a loop, it doesn't work...

```
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        htmls[i] = "<div style=\"margin-bottom:10px; \"><table><tr><td><img src=\"" + result[i].UserImageURI + "\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\" /></td><td style=\"vertical-align:top; \"><strong>" + result[i].Username + "</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (" + result[i].Age + ")<br/>" + result[i].Country + "<br/>" + result[i].Distance + " KMs away<br/><a href=\"profile.aspx?lfid=" + result[i].Userid + "\">View Profile</a></td></tr></table></div>";
        latlngs[i] = new GLatLng(result[i].Latitude, result[i].Longitude);
        if (result[i].Gender == "F") {
            markers[i] = new GMarker(latlngs[i], { draggable: false, icon: fIcon });
        } else {
            markers[i] = new GMarker(latlngs[i], { draggable: false, icon: mIcon });
        }
        GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", function () {
            markers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
        });
        map.addOverlay(markers[i]);
    }
```

When using the loop, clicking on a marker breaks the script. It points to the line

markers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);

And says that object is undefined. It also says that i = 10 at that point which is "impossible" as results.length is only 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the [classic function-in-a-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Here's one of the two typical ways to fix it:

```
function callback(i) {
    return function () {
        markers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
    };
}

for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // snip...
    
    GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", callback(i));
    
    // snip...   
}
```

[JSLint](http://jslint.com/) can easily catch these common errors.

---

#### Edit

[@Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353187/problems-with-javascript-loop-adding-gmarker-to-gmap/6353224#6353224) shows roughly the other typical way that this problem is fixed, but with a few errors. This should work, though:

```
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // snip...
    
    GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", (function (i) {
        return function () {
            markers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
        }
    })(i));
    
    // snip...   
}
```

Comment: Oh yep, I fixed it at the same time too :) +1 for the hint

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that doesn't work either.

var latlngs = [10];
var markers = [10];
var htmls = [10];
function callback(j) { return function (j) { markers[j].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[j]); }; }
function setIconsCB(result) {
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    ...
    GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", callback(i));
    ...
}

Same problem... Object is undefined and i = 10

Comment: The function that `callback` returns should not take a parameter. Change `function callback(j) { return function (j) { ...` to `function callback(j) { return function () { ...` as in my answer.

Comment: OK guys, thanks a lot... I can get both versions to work now :) I guess I will use the nested function in the edited alex' answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code...

```
GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", function () {
        markers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
});
```

...the function has closure to the `i` in the parent scope. So it is accessing the variable itself, **not** a copy of it.

At the end of the loop, when your function accesses the `i` variable, it will be equal to whatever condition stopped the loop, `10` in your example.

You can fix it with a self invoking anonymous function which passes the value to a new variable with a limited lifespan...

```
(function(j) {  
    GEvent.addListener(markers[j], "click", function () {
           markers[j].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[j]);
    });
})(i);
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/EwJv9/) of similar code working.

Comment: Should `htmls[i]` be `htmls[j]` ?